# Adding Blur effect to BufferredImage in Java

Tags: java, image-processing

I am writing a Image Processing project.
Everything is done except blur effect.
The common simple algorithm says :

1. Take the 8 pixels surrounding your pixel and your pixel
2. Average the RGB values of all 9 pixels and stick them in your current pixel location
3. Repeat for every pixel

Below the I implemented to add blur effect

```
BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(),
            img.getHeight(), img.getType());

    int height = img.getHeight();
    int width = img.getWidth();

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {

            int pixel1 = (x == 0 || y == 0) ? 0 : img.getRGB(x - 1, y - 1);
            int pixel2 = (y == 0) ? 0 : img.getRGB(x, y - 1);
            int pixel3 = (y == 0 || x >= width-1) ? 0 : img.getRGB(x + 1, y - 1);
            int pixel4 = (x == 0) ? 0 :img.getRGB(x - 1, y);
            int pixel5 = img.getRGB(x, y);
            int pixel6 = (x >= height -1) ? 0 :img.getRGB(x + 1, y);
            int pixel7 = (x == 0 || y >= height -1) ? 0 :img.getRGB(x - 1, y + 1);
            int pixel8 = (y >= height -1) ? 0 :img.getRGB(x, y + 1);
            int pixel9 = (x >= width-1 || y >= height - 1) ? 0 :img.getRGB(x + 1, y + 1);

            int newPixel = pixel1 + pixel2 + pixel3 + pixel4 + pixel5
                    + pixel6 + pixel7 + pixel8 + pixel9;

            newPixel = newPixel/9;

            int redAmount = (newPixel >> 16) & 0xff;
            int greenAmount = (newPixel >> 8) & 0xff;
            int blueAmount = (newPixel >> 0) & 0xff;

            newPixel = (redAmount<< 16) | (greenAmount << 8) | blueAmount ;
            result.setRGB(x, y, newPixel);
        }
```

I got noisy image as result rather than blurred image.
I think I am doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance.
**Note : Any external API is restricted like Kernal, AffineTransfomation or etc...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is version with just loops:

```
BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), img.getType()) ;
final int H = img.getHeight() - 1 ;
final int W = img.getWidth() - 1 ;

for (int c=0 ; c < img.getRaster().getNumBands() ; c++) // for all the channels/bands
    for (int x=1 ; x < W ; x++) // For all the image
        for (int y=1; y < H ; y++)
            {
            int newPixel = 0 ;
            for (int i=-1 ; i <= 1 ; i++) // For the neighborhood
                for (int j=-1 ; j <= 1 ; j++)
                    newPixel += img.getRaster().getSample(x+i, y+j, c) ;
            newPixel = (int)(newPixel/9.0 + 0.5) ;
            result.getRaster().setSample(x, y, c, newPixel) ;
            }
```

Don't use getRGB, it's really slow and you have to deal with the conversions. getSample does everything for you.

Comment: Can you tell me why you added 0.5 in newPixel/9.0 ?

Comment: I round the resulting value to the closest int. If the result is 1.9, your method round it to 1, with mine, it rounds it to 2. It's the most common way to go from double to int. It is done by Math.round() as well.

Comment: I have other 7 filters included as well. What we learned and implemented is to use getRGB() method. I like your was as it is very much optimized code. But I have to use getRGB() for now. And yes I will implement two neighbour inner loops.

Comment: The most optimized solution is to access directly the DataBuffer, then you work directly on the array. I don't know why getRGB() is imposed, but it is the worst solution to access the pixels value.

Comment: May be because its just beginner level.

Comment: I thought I will not be able to select any answer till 2 days. Hmm when selecting own answer only.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do calculations with the raw RGB integers like you do. This will certainly cause wrong results. (e.g. integer overflows)
You have to take care of the each color component on their own.

**Edit** Just to give you an example: think about what it would mean to calculate the "average" of two pixels 00FFFF and 0000CC?.

What you actually want as result is something like 007FE5, but calculating with the raw integers will cause the "blue" part to be carried over to the yellow part resulting in 008065.

Comment: Let me calculate average for all red, blue and green color and then set. And see if it works.

Comment: Yay, cool. Please accept my answer for closing this question then.

Answer (score 0):

As I said written algorithms are proved. Just forgot to calculate the average for red, green and blue separately.
Here is the answer.

```
BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(),
            img.getHeight(), img.getType());

    int height = img.getHeight();
    int width = img.getWidth();

    for (int x = 1; x < width-1; x++)
        for (int y = 1; y < height-1; y++) {

            int redAmount = 0;
            int greenAmount = 0;
            int blueAmount = 0;

            int pixel1 = img.getRGB(x - 1, y - 1);
            redAmount += (pixel1 >> 16) & 0xff;
            greenAmount += (pixel1 >> 8) & 0xff;
            blueAmount += (pixel1 >> 0) & 0xff;

            int pixel2 = img.getRGB(x, y - 1);
            redAmount += (pixel2 >> 16) & 0xff;
            greenAmount += (pixel2 >> 8) & 0xff;
            blueAmount += (pixel2 >> 0) & 0xff;

            int pixel3 = img.getRGB(x + 1, y - 1);
            redAmount += (pixel3 >> 16) & 0xff;
            greenAmount += (pixel3 >> 8) & 0xff;
            blueAmount += (pixel3 >> 0) & 0xff;

            int pixel4 = img.getRGB(x - 1, y);
            redAmount += (pixel4 >> 16) & 0xff;
            greenAmount += (pixel4 >> 8) & 0xff;
            blueAmount += (pixel4 >> 0) & 0xff;

            int pixel5 = img.getRGB(x, y);
            redAmount += (pixel5 >> 16) & 0xff;
            greenAmount += (pixel5 >> 8) & 0xff;
            blueAmount += (pixel5 >> 0) & 0xff;

            int pixel6 = img.getRGB(x + 1, y);
            redAmount += (pixel6 >> 16) & 0xff;
            greenAmount += (pixel6 >> 8) & 0xff;
            blueAmount += (pixel6 >> 0) & 0xff;

            int pixel7 = img.getRGB(x - 1, y + 1);
            redAmount += (pixel7 >> 16) & 0xff;
            greenAmount += (pixel7 >> 8) & 0xff;
            blueAmount += (pixel7 >> 0) & 0xff;

            int pixel8 = img.getRGB(x, y + 1);
            redAmount += (pixel8 >> 16) & 0xff;
            greenAmount += (pixel8 >> 8) & 0xff;
            blueAmount += (pixel8 >> 0) & 0xff;

            int pixel9 = img.getRGB(x + 1, y + 1);
            redAmount += (pixel9 >> 16) & 0xff;
            greenAmount += (pixel9 >> 8) & 0xff;
            blueAmount += (pixel9 >> 0) & 0xff;

            redAmount /= 9;
            greenAmount /= 9;
            blueAmount /= 9;

            int newPixel = (redAmount << 16) | (greenAmount << 8) | blueAmount;
            result.setRGB(x, y, newPixel);
        }
```

Comment: I have modified loops to start from 1 to width-1/height-1, that removes unneccessary ternary operators in code.